# Fastest way to extract matching strings

Tags: python, algorithm, search, complexity-theory

I want to search for words that match a given word in a list (example below). However, say there is a list that contain millions of words. What is the most efficient way to perform this search?. I was thinking of tokenizing each list and putting the words in hashtable. Then perform the word search / match and retrieve the list of words that contain this word. From what I can see is this operation will take O(n) operations. Is there any other way? may be without using hash-tables?.

```
words_list = ['yek', 'lion', 'opt'];
# e.g. if we were to search or match the word "key" with the words in the list we should get the word "yek" or a list of words if there many that match
```

Also, is there a python library or third party package that can perform efficient searches?

Comment: By "match" do you mean "has the same set of characters", so `keey` matches `yekk`, or "has the same multiset of characters", or something different?

Comment: I don't see how it could take less than O(n) time. you need to search through an unordered set.

Comment: Not the 1st! But words that have the same characters regardless of the order. And, it's okay if it must take more than O(n), just share some suggestions please?

Comment: @geek-qs I already wrote you an answer. If you update your question to be clearer and more specific, I can shorten the answer and reorganize it to focus on your exact question rather than being completely general.

Comment: Are you doing lots of lookups on the same words_list, or just doing one lookup and then throwing it away? And, either way, how are you generating the list?

Comment: Here is another example. Let's say am looking if thereis a match for word 'python' in this list ['thonpy','onpyth','thonpyy','oonpythh','yothpn']. Only these 'thonpy','onpyth','yothpn' match the word 'python'. Please, am looking for you suggestions on how to make the process when I have millions of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear when you mean by "match" here, but if you can reduce that to an identity comparison, the problem reduces to a set lookup, which is O(1) time.

For example, if "match" means "has exactly the same set of characters":

```
words_set = {frozenset(word) for word in words_list}
```

Then, to look up a word:

```
frozenset(word) in words_set
```

Or, if it means "has exactly the same multiset of characters" (i.e., counting duplicates but ignoring order):

```
words_set = {sorted(word) for word in words_list}

sorted(word) in words_set
```

… or, if you prefer:

```
words_set = {collections.Counter(word) for word in words_list}

collections.Counter(word) in words_set
```

Either way, the key (no pun intended… but maybe it should have been) idea here is to come up with a transformation that turns your values (strings) into values that are identical iff they match (a set of characters, a multiset of characters, an ordered list of sorted characters, etc.). Then, the whole point of a set is that it can look for a value that's equal to your value in constant time.

Of course transforming the list takes O(N) time (unless you just build the transformed set in the first place, instead of building the list and then converting it), but you can use it over and over, and it takes O(1) time each time instead of O(N), which is what it sounds like you care about.

---

If you need to get back the matching word rather than just know that there is one, you can still do this with a set, but it's easier (if you can afford to waste a bit of space) with a dict:

```
words_dict = {frozenset(word): word for word in words_list}

words_dict[frozenset(word)] # KeyError if no match
```

---

If there could be multiple matches, just change the dict to a multidict:

```
words_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
for word in words_list:
    words_dict[frozenset(word)].add(word)

words_dict[frozenset(word)] # empty set if no match
```

Or, if you explicitly want it to be a list rather than a set:

```
words_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for word in words_list:
    words_dict[frozenset(word)].append(word)

words_dict[frozenset(word)] # empty list if no match
```

---

If you want to do it without using hash tables (why?), you can use a search tree or other logarithmic data structure:

```
import blist # pip install blist to get it

words_dict = blist.sorteddict()
for word in words_list:
    words_dict.setdefault(word, set()).add(word)

words_dict[frozenset(word)] # KeyError if no match
```

This looks almost identical, except for the fact that it's not quite trivial to wrap `defaultdict` around a `blist.sorteddict`—but that just takes a few lines of code. (And maybe you actually want a `KeyError` rather than an empty set, so I figured it was worth showing both defaultdict and normal dict with setdefault somewhere, so you can choose.)

But under the covers, it's using a hybrid B-tree variant instead of a hash table. Although this is O(log N) time instead of O(1), in some cases it's actually faster than a dict.